# Взятие переменных NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Пытаюсь взять 1 переменную из index.html с помощью:

server.js:

```
router.get("/addNum", function (req, res) {
    var i = `${input1}`;
    console.log(i);
    buttonAction1(res, i);
});
```

index.html

```
function addSome() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'addNum', success: function (res) {
                    var i = $("#input1").val();
                    i = new Number(i);
                    console.log(i);

                    $("#out").text(res, input1.value);
                }
            });
        }
```

И проблема только в этой строчке:

```
var i = `${input1}`;
```

Есит ли выход из такого случая и как таким образов взять параметр.

Comment: никак. Серверный скрипт никак не связан с клиентским

Comment: Почти связан, осталось только в тело аякс запроса добавить то, что нужно, а в req выкопать

Comment: @vp_arth а можно разъяснить?